# Can I print a number without assigning it to a variable first?

Tags: c

For example, can I do `printf("%d",1);`, or do I have to assign `1` to a variable first?
Also, when I try `prinf("%d",2.5)`, the output is not the integer part, but a weird number such as `602556751`. Why?

Comment: Please only ask one question per question.

Comment: Concerning question 1: what happens when you try?

Comment: Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*. For example using the `%d` format, which is for `int` values, to print `2.5` which is a `double` floating-point value.

Comment: The arguments to `printf` must match the data types expected by the corresponding format specifiers.  It will not cast arguments for you the way it could if it had type information from the function prototype.

Comment: You’re confusing the format specifier with the behaviour of implicit conversions between types.

Comment: When you pass a value as an argument to be output by `printf()`, the compiler does not consider the format specifiers that were used (except to generate a warning of type mismatch). It does however make promotions: integer values of types smaller than `int` are promoted to `int`, and `float` values are promoted to `double`. This means that the format `%f` specifies `double` (unlike with `scanf` where it specifies a `float` target).

Comment: @Brian61354270: Asking about `%f` with an `int` and `%d` with a `double` are closely related and quite reasonable to ask together and to answer together.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If that were what was asked, I would agree. But the first question is about whether there's any difference between passing constants vs variables, which is unrelated to the second question about mismatching format specifiers and argument types.

Comment: @Brian61354270: They are still closely related and reasonable to ask together.

Comment: You can. But why `printf("%d",1);` and not `printf("1");`?

Answer (score 1):

> printf("%d",1); I wonder that I can do like this or %d %f and any of them can only use with variable like printf("%d",num);…

C does not provide abstract mathematics where you can freely work with numbers of all kinds. It works with values represented by bytes, using a system of types such as `int`, `float`, `double`, and so on. In asking C to do things, you must keep in mind the types involved. Further, when calling a function, all arguments are passed as values in particular types. C never passes a “variable” to a function, just a value. If `num` is an `int` with value 1, then `printf("%d", 1)` and `printf("%d", num)` are the same; both pass the `int` value 1 to `printf`.

In a C implementation with a four-byte `int` and a four-byte `float`, the same four bytes may represent a different value depending on what type they are interpreted with. With the `int` type, the bits in the bytes represent a binary numeral, and the value represented by that numeral is the value of the `int`. (The bits do not form a pure binary numeral, as some provision is made for encoding negative numbers. That is not discussed in this answer.)

With the format commonly used for `float`, one bit represents a sign, eight bits primarily encode an exponent that is used to scale the value, and 23 bits encode a fraction value called a significand. (The full significand has 24 bits, one of which is derived from the exponent bits.)

In `printf("%d", 1);`, the `%d` tells `printf` “I am passing an `int` value, and I want it formatted in decimal.” `printf` responds to that by looking in the arguments passed to it for the bytes of an `int` and interpreting those bytes as a binary numeral. If you execute `printf("%f", 1);`, that tells `printf` to look for the bytes of a `double`. (For historic reasons, `float` values are passed as `double` values when passed for the variable argument portion of a function call.) Then there are two problems:

- By passing `1`, the bytes you pass are encoded using the scheme for an `int`. If `printf` interprets them as the bytes of a `double`, it will generally produce a different value, especially since a `double` usually requires more bytes than an `int`.
- The rules of some computing platforms specify to pass the bytes for a `double` argument in a different place than the bytes for an `int` argument. When `printf` fetches the bytes for `double`, but you have passed an `int`, it will not get the bytes you passed it. It will get some other bytes leftover in the location that `printf` gets the bytes from.

Formally, the C standard does not define the behavior when you pass the wrong type of argument for a conversion specifier.

> … and I have another question I try prinf("%d",2.5). I think output should be the integer part of 2.5 but The output is weird number such as 602556751. Where does this number come from?

`2.5` is a `double`. When you executed this, `%d` informed `printf` to expect an `int`, so `printf` attempted to get the bytes for an `int`, which are passed in a different location than the bytes for a `double`. So it likely got some bytes that were left in that location from previous work in your program. It interpreted those bytes as an `int` and printed them.

In order for `%d` to work with a `double` or `%f` to work with an `int`, the compiler would have to convert the argument before calling the function. For `printf`, it would have to examine the format string to determine the conversions to make. That is possible with a constant format string, but a program could also compute a format string and pass it by pointer instead of using a constant format string, and then the compiler would have no way of knowing what conversions to perform. Additionally, there are other functions that use variable argument lists with other methods of determining the argument types, instead of a format string, and the compiler would also have no way of handling those. The programmer is responsible for passing arguments of the correct types.